# ¿cómo crear un filtro por precio de producto?

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy haciendo un pequeña tienda en linea, pero a la hora de crear un filtro para seleccionar los productos por precio no se como realizarlo, ya que son de múltiples tablas que debo sacar los productos de acuerdo al intervalo de precio; por ejemplo, tengo mi tabla bancas, sillas, mesas y todas a su ves tienen el campo precio de tipo int, quiero que mi consulta extraiga todos los productos que tengan precio entre 1000-300, 3000-5000, 5000-700 y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes mostrar más informacíon sobre lo que estas haciendo para que te podamos sugerir diferentes variantes.
Podrías ir mirando MySQL: BETWEEN Condition, Operator Union, JOIN https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/

Este código mysql te puede ayudar.

```
(select
     `precio`,
     `nombre`
   from `bancas`
   where `precio` between 200 and 1000)
  union
  (select
     `precio`,
     `nombre`
   from `sillas`
   where `precio` between 200 and 1000)
  union
  (select
     `precio`,
     `nombre`
   from `mesas`
   where precio between 200 and 1000)
```

Aquí obtengo todos los productos que tengan precio en el rango [200-1000].

Para ayudarte un poco más debes escribir la estructura de tus tablas, asumí que existe un campo `nombre`. saludos espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: hola, la consulta que quiero hacer realmente es "selecionar todos los productos de la tabla sillas, mesas, bancas, recepcion donde el precio este entre 1000 y 200" dependiendo de la opcion que elija el usuario